# Interstatial Admob using PhoneGap not working

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, interstitial

I'm trying to display interstitial Ad in my PhoneGap app but it's not working; it's not displaying the ad at all. I followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial).

Apart from trying to make it work, what I also need to do is to show the interstitial at a particular time (probably when the game is over) but I dont know how to refer to the Java code from JavaScript code to show the loaded interstitial ad.

Please help.

Comment: Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently got AdMob working within my Cordova 4 project after much fiddling. Forget the instructions you linked to in your question, which are not for cordova/phonegap builds.

**Step 1**: You will need to install the Cordova/Phonegap plugin for Admob. (This assumes you have [already created the project files](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface).) In my case, e.g. for Cordova command line interface, I used Terminal, `cd` to my project's root directory and then type:

```
cordova plugin add com.admob.google
```

For your Phonegap setup, you will likely need to do **one of the following**:

Add this to your project's config.xml file.

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.google" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

**OR**  (for Phonegap CLI), type this command into Terminal from your project's root directory,

```
phonegap local plugin add com.admob.google
```

Once you have the plugin, you can use javascript to control Admob behavior.

**Step 2**: Add appropriate javascript for Admob plugin to your project, linked in your index.html file. I ran into some trouble here, so just to prove to myself that the plugin really works, I removed (backed up) everything from my project's WWW folder and added the exact files from the WWW folder from [this project](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova) and later [this one](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-phonegap-build-demo) on Github. Both work. It was then a matter of making smarter-people-than-myself's javascript work in my app.

**A few tips**

- Don't use the emulator. Admob may not perform correctly in the emulator.
- For some reason, I am not served Admob ads over LTE/4G. If you are certain you have done everthing correctly, try connecting your device to WIFI when testing
- If your app is still not working, and you don't know what elese to do, try to [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). Invalid html will affect performance of javascript.
- Make sure you have added `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` in your head of your index file.

Comment: Hi, when I tried to add `<gap:plugin name="com.admob.google" source="plugins.cordova.io" />` to the config.xml file in the project home folder, it automatically updates it to the config.xml file in `res/xml/config.xml` which gives error when I try to build:  
`error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`

Comment: Hi @user2070999 , thanks for your great help and pointing me to the  right js code. It's working now. However, I removed the `<gap:plugin name="com.admob.google" source="plugins.cordova.io" />` from the `config.xml` due to the error it was giving me while building. But yet, it works :). Thanks man. You made my day. Happy new year!!!

Comment: Great! Glad it is working. Since you mentioned adding `<gap:plugin name="com.admob.google"`... caused an error, I am going to link to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605254/phonegap-desktop-app-external-plugins). As with Cordova, there are a few different ways of adding plugins depending on your Cordova/phonegap setup. If you are using PhoneGap CLI, you probably typed `phonegap local plugin add com.admob.google` to add the plugin successfully, without needing to add the other code to the confix.xml file. I'll edit the original answer so add this to step 1.

Comment: Hi @user2070999 , I've been following the first link in the step 2 and it shows both banner and interstitial ads. However, it doesn't reflect on my Admob account. No clicks or fill rate or request. Nothing atall. I did used my ad codes of course and clicked on the ads to test. Have you encountered this problem before? Have a way out of this?

Comment: My guess: if you followed the [admob-phonegap-build-demo](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-phonegap-build-demo), you are missing one of these configurations:1. Replace the `interstitial` and the `banner` codes in index.js with codes from your actual admob account  _e.g. something like ca-app-pub-84403..._ It sounds like you did this okay already.  2. make sure `isTesting:` is NOT set to true in the index.js file. Set to `false`. If you are able to get a test ad, you should be able to see a real ad when set to true. See if you can at least get the impressions to start counting. Good luck.

Comment: Idid 1 already. For 2, there is no `isTesting` in the code I used. I has `var admobid = (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? adPublisherIds.android : adPublisherIds.ios;` instead. That's the only line I can find something related to `test`. Do I need to change something here? The requests and impressions works fine I think, just the clicking that doesnt show anything. It has been like that since.

Comment: Hmm. `isTesting:` appears in the .js file for both examples in Step 2. I just noticed that one is called index.js and the other is called admob.js. Let me send a link to both. Here is [#1](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/blob/master/www/admob.js) and [#2](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-phonegap-build-demo/blob/master/www/js/index.js).