# Admob Interstitial ad not linking to app store when clicked

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, admob, interstitial

I have an app developed for iOS using Phonegap cordova and Admob (via javascript) integrated into it. Both the banner and interstitial ads display well, banner ads links to the app store when clicked but all Interstitial ad displayed does not link to the app store. Sometimes it just hangs in there and cannot even close some ads.

Has anyone experienced this before? Can you please help me on this?

I followed the [instructions here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686998/interstatial-admob-using-phonegap-not-working/27697809?noredirect=1)

Comment: are you using a plugin for admob? then share the link.

Comment: Hi @jcesarmobile I've updated the question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686998/interstatial-admob-using-phonegap-not-working/27697809?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the solution to what's causing the problem. I tried to refresh/reload the ad every 2 minutes by using this code:

`showNextInterstitial = setTimeout(function() {
   admob.requestInterstitialAd();
  }, 2 * 60 * 1000);`

I guess it hangs the interstitial ad once it displays.