# Phonegap desktop not launching properly ..keeps loading

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

[image: Phonegap desktop launching creen]

I have installed phonegap desktop v(0.3.0) on windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: Same thing happens for me.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. anand did you solved this?

Comment: @Haris..I'm still struggling :(

Comment: @Haris download the new version https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/releases

Comment: i'm using the latest version and this still happens with me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Problem got resolved.  downloaded the new version (0.3.1) from below link and installed it

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/releases

Answer (score 1):

it appears that the 0.3.0 release was problematic.

There is a new version (0.3.1) to address the issue.

See this Blog post for details:
[PhoneGap Desktop App 0.3.1](http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/04/21/phonegap-app-desktop-0-3-1/)

- Download for [Mac](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/desktop-app/install/mac/)
- Download for [Windows](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/desktop-app/install/win/)

Comment: I downloaded the windows version from this link and problem still exist there. Phonegap Desktop goes on just loading...... continously. Seems CLI is good option

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla Looks like Adobe is bailing on PhoneGap https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806662/3606700

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going to the phonegap directory and running (as administrator) the batch file "resources \ app.asar.unpacked \ bin \ **postInstall.bat**"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the initial cause in this case was solved (at that time), but for those stumbling onto this thread in the future. Phonegap build has stopped working because Adobe has stopped supporting it.

Per [The Adobe forum](https://community.adobe.com/t5/phonegap/the-death-of-phonegap-real-or-not/td-p/10813752)

> PhoneGap Build is in maintenance mode, no further active work is being done by Adobe.

There may be [ways to get it working](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/913#issuecomment-571156198), but it's questionable, at what point will the entire Build platform be taken down? Probably best to turn away from Phonegap entirely and rely on the Cordova CLI.