# Desktop not launching properly

Tags: phonegap

Phonegap desktop not is launching properly. It is stuck and keeps loading. I am using version 0.4.5.

[image]

Comment: Even after re-installing?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, just now! I resolved it in this [way](https://community.adobe.com/t5/phonegap/phonegap-desktop-app-not-working/m-p/10987959?page=1#M5074).

1. Install the desktop app using the win32 binary (0.4.5 beta)
2. Downloaded the Node.js version 6 x86 zip (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/node-v6.17.1-win-x86.zip)
3. In the zip file, go to node_modules folder, extract the NPM folder, and zip the NPM folder into NPM.zip
4. Navigate to the 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar.unpacked\bin' folder, and replaced NPM.zip with the one I created.
5. Opened cmd, navigated to the same folder, and ran postInstall.bat

This is what it looks like, it has errors. But the end of it says Download complete!

CMD screenshot:
[image: CMD screenshot]

I then run the Phonegap Desktop and it works. No more stuck in loading screen.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I solved by installed the older version like 0.3.1 and it runs without any issue. It will populate to update v0.4.5 but don't update it will produce same issue.

Download the older version from this link [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/releases.).
This is the version I tried [0.3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w03xk.png).

After install the older version, it will appear [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d8l0.png).

If you find any working solution for v0.4.5 please share your solution here.

Comment: That's strange, version 0.4.5 has never given me any issues. Are you using Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Adobe has stopped supporting Phonegap, and seemingly starting to pull the plug on the entire thing.

Per [The Adobe forum](https://community.adobe.com/t5/phonegap/the-death-of-phonegap-real-or-not/td-p/10813752)

> PhoneGap Build is in maintenance mode, no further active work is being done by Adobe.

There may be [ways to get it working](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/913#issuecomment-571156198), but it's questionable, at what point will the entire Build platform be taken down? Probably best to turn away from Phonegap entirely and rely on the Cordova CLI.